# Django: Getting a list of meetings that a certain user is in

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am trying to get a list of meetings that a user is in, so that I can display them on a calendar. I have the following in `models.py`:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, null=True, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

class Meeting(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)

class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Essentially, a user and a meeting are linked in the Member model. I have the following function in `database.py`, which creates a new Meeting:

```
def createMeeting(name, location, admin, start_date, end_date, description):
    new = Meeting(name=name, location=location, admin=admin, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, description=description)
    if not duplicate(Meeting, new):
        new.save()

    membership = Member(user=admin, meeting=new)
    if not duplicate(Member, membership):
        membership.save()
```

For a certain user that is logged in, I want to be able to get a list of all the meetings that they are a member of. I know that I will need to use the Member model, but I am not sure what is the best method to get all the meetings a user is in. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your meetings with:

```
Meeting.objects.filter(member__user=request.user)
```

This will return all `Meeting`s for which there exists a *related* `Member` object with as `user` the `request.user`.

Comment: You may need to add a `related_name` to the `ForeignKey`s in `Member` to make this style of syntax work.

Comment: @HarryVane: if you do not specify a `related_name` or `related_query_name`, the default `related_query_name` is the name of the model (in lowercase). If you specify a `related_query_name`, or a `related_name`, that is the `related_query_name`.